# Nodejs app launch in 1 click

Tags: node.js, batch-file, exe, executable, ini

I have a small node app in a github repo.

I want my users to be able to clone the app folder to any location on their computer and launch my app:

eg:
d:/
c:/my documents/
e:/myfiles/node/apps/

I want a file, I dont care if it's an *.ini a *.bat or an *.exe.

I want them to double click that file and launch my node app.

usually to launch I have to open CMD in the location and type

```
node app.js
```

Comment: you can do that with a batch file, as some answers said. But I've seen that in Linux you can run a .js file directly in the desktop by adding ```#!/usr/bin/env node``` in the first line. Does anyone knows if that exist for windows?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows, you can create a batch file as follows to run a node app:

Make a .bat file e.g. app.bat

```
@echo off
cd "c:/myfiles/node/apps/"
node app.js
exit
```

Then the user can click app.bat to run your app.

I imagine you would use a bash script for mac osx, I haven't tried that, but it should work.

Comment: I need this bit to be generic to any location, where the file is currently...
cd "c:/myfiles/node/apps/"

Comment: And of course average user doesn't have node installed.

Comment: okay maybe you don't need that 2nd line then it should work okay, good point Aleksandr they would need node installed.

Comment: I did see this [deskshell](https://github.com/sihorton/appjs-deskshell/) which can convert node.js apps to desktop apps, I would assume to executables

Comment: I don't mind them having to install node first, but then 1 click start up so its easier. I will check DeskShell

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file extension to .bat and add the following code at the beginning:

```
rem/*
@node %0&exit/b&*/=0
```

When run as a batch script, this code will run the file that it's in with Node.js and then exit.

When run as a Node.js script, this code will set the rem variable to 0.